# Adding a resizable scroll-bar in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text, tkinter-scrolledtext

I am new to Tkinter. I am trying to add a scroll-bar in the GUI that I created using Tkinter. I added the scroll-bar using the following program. But, the problem is that, when I resize my window using mouse cursor, the size of the scrollbar also changes. I want the size of the scroll-bar to remain same in proportion to the size of the screen. I am not sure how to do that.

Also, there is no restriction that I have to use `pack()` I can use any other geometry manager.

the code:

```
import tkinter as tk


# Execute a multi-thread programming
class GUI():
    def __init__(self):

        # Define the default size of the window
        self.HEIGHT = 750
        self.WIDTH = 700
        self.play_pause = False

        # Define the GUI window.

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("GUI window")
        self.root.geometry(newGeometry=f"{self.WIDTH}x{self.HEIGHT}")
        self.root.minsize(self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT)

        self.frame3 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root, text="Output window", height=450, width=700)
        self.frame3.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.output_text = tk.Text(self.frame3, height=42, fg="white", bg="black")
        self.output_text.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Create a scroll bar for the Text widget
        v = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame3, orient='vertical', command=self.output_text.yview)
        v.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = GUI()
    app.root.mainloop()
```

The output that I am getting.

[image]

What happens when I resize

[image]

Comment: Change `v.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)` to `v.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)`.

Comment: There was also one more small thing, when using scroll bar, if the output exceeds the size of the screen, I want the output to show directly the last line and then I should be able to scroll up in the GUI.

Comment: You can use `self.output_text.see("end")` to scroll to the end of the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn off the `expand` option. Either accept the default, or explicitly set it to `False`. When set to `True` it tells pack to allocate extra space from the window to that widget, which you don't want.